# pgfplotstable: typset csv with 2 or more header lines (eg. name, unit, comment)

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, external-files, lua

I am exporting from Origin and get a Data.csv like this:

```
Short_Name1; Short_Name2
Long_Name1;  Long_Name2
Unit1;       Unit2
Comment1;    Comment2
1,1;         2,0
3,5;         4,3
```

When I try to print that with pgfplotstable, I need to do something like:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}


%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{
            pgfplotstable,
            booktabs,
            array,
            colortbl,
            }

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period,
    fixed,
    zerofill,
%   string type,
    precision=2,
    ignore chars={\_},
   %dec sep align, %prints both strings in first column, aligned at the comma
%
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule },
       after row={\midrule },
        },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
        },
    every even row/.style={
        before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.985}}}, %also a problem
%
    %every row 0/.style={string type}, %does not work
%    \directlua{    for i = 0, 2 do  %does also not work
%               for j= 0,1 do 
%                   tex.sprint( "every row ",i," column ",j,"\noexpand/.style={string type}, " ) 
%               end
%           end }
    every row 0 column 0/.style={string type},
    every row 0 column 1/.style={string type},
    every row 1 column 0/.style={string type},
    every row 1 column 1/.style={string type},
    every row 2 column 0/.style={string type},
    every row 2 column 1/.style={string type},
%
    every row 2/.style={
        after row={\midrule },
        },
]
    {Data.csv} 

%looks like it should as workaround, but is not processed properly
\directlua{     for i = 0, 2 do
            for j= 0,1 do 
                tex.sprint( "every row ",i," column ",j,"\noexpand/.style={string type}, " ) 
            end
        end }



\end{document}
```

Is there any more convenient way of doing that?

I would also be happy if it was possible to get

```
Long_Name1 [Unit1]
```

as one header line and ignore the two remaining string lines. It is no problem to export just two of them via Origin.

EDIT:
I already tried `every row no 0/.style={string type},`, it produces an error.

`header=false` will result in columns named `0 1 2 3` and so it would need to give each column name as

```
columns/<index>/.style={
        string type,
        column type=l,
        column name={Long_Name [Unit]}
        },
```

EDIT2: `header=false`-"Problem" is already solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238938/77098)

So I will try to do the processing

```
Long_Name1;  Long_Name2
Unit1;       Unit2
1,1;         2,0
3,5;         4,3
```

to

```
Long_Name1 [\si{Unit1}];  Long_Name2 [\si{Unit2}]
1,1;         2,0
3,5;         4,3
```

with lua (python would be easier…) but not even my code to generate
`every row 0 column 0/.style={string type},`
did work (and it definitely prints that line when it runs outside pgfplotstable).

I thought that must be some usual workflow and there has to be a simple solution already…

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` to help avoid the setup phase for the users interested in providing an answer.

Comment: There are some useful keys like `header=false` and `every row no 0` and `every row no 1`. But I believe that PGFPLOTS does not encourage header-processing so why not accomplish `Long_Name1 [Unit1]` outside TeX?

Comment: To answer, I edited my question for better readability.