# How can I force a specific order of magnitude in a column?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have to process some tables with `pgfplotstable` which are stored in a `.dat` file I'd like to input without pre-processing it myself.

The numbers in the columns are in scientific notation, and I'm looking for a way to set every entry in the same order of magnitude.
One of those columns looks like

```
0.233e-3
0.48e-3
0.69e-3
0.95e-3
0.103e-2
9.23e-5
```

and I'd like to have them properly in the same order, say `e-3`.
Is there a way I can do it?
I read the package manual but I didn't find such an option.

Comment: You can use `siunitx` package column type for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41619/table-typesetting-with-pgfplotstable

Comment: Ah, found it! It is enough to set the `fixed-exponent` section in `sisetup`.